# Crystal report shows no data

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

I have a crystal report that should import data from tables from a dataset. 
Dataset contains 3 tables faktura, kund, varor (Swedish, its Invoice, customer, Order)
The problem is that the Crystal shows data only from 'varor'  and if i add any data from 'kund' or 'faktura'  the reports becomes empty and no data comes up. 
Im sura that these tables in my dataset are filled from my DB.

Here my code that filling the tables

```
{
MySqlDataAdapter adbtr = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();

        adbtr  = MySkul.readDataAdbter("Select * from kund where id= '"+_kundId+"' ");
        adbtr.Fill(ds1, "kund");

        adbtr= MySkul.readDataAdbter("Select  * from faktura where Id='"+30+"' ");
        adbtr.Fill(ds1, "faktura");

        adbtr = MySkul.readDataAdbter("SELECT * FROM varor AS v JOIN ordervaror AS o ON v.Id = o.idVara WHERE idOrder =(SELECT MAX(Id) FROM ordern)");
        adbtr.Fill(ds1, "varor");

      CrystalReport1 rprt = new CrystalReport1();
        rprt.SetDataSource(ds1);

        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rprt;

   }
```

Comment: I don't have any expertise in CR as a part of C# but by seeing your code.. my guess is in your where clause you are picking only those records that are equal to certain `ID` may be there is no data for what you are trying to view.. I advice you to display all 3 tables in report without where clause and see the result

Comment: Do you have access to the database so you can run each of these queries directly and make sure they work?

Comment: your ID Data Type is Int or Nvarchar ?

Comment: @Ally yes im sure that is returning data from my data base.

Comment: @SOFKiNG it's int and auto incremented item

Comment: i think each datasourse override previous one !change code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have fixed it
The problem was that these tables had relations to each other. 
Removed the relations/ links between tables on Data base expert since im not running any query , im finnling my dataset whith the data i want by MySqlqueries befor i upload the report, so no need to have or run anyqyery on the report.